# How to get particular column distinct in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, model-view-controller

I am having columns as category and songs in my table for each category. There are almost 10 songs and in total there are 7 categories such that it is tabled as

```
category1 songCategory1a
category1 songCategory1b
category1 songCategory1c
---
---
--
category2 songCategory2a
category2 songCategory2b
category2 songCategory2c
---
---
---
category3 songCategory3a
category3 songCategory3b
category3 songCategory3c
---
---
---
```

Like that there is a table in which I want to get the result as

category1
category2
category3
category4

I tried:

```
(from s in _context.db_songs
     select new { s.Song_Name, s.Song_Category }).Distinct().ToList();
```

But it didn't work. Its resulting as such.

Answer (score 4):

When you need to get distinct rows, you need to supply only the column you want get distinct data from:

```
(from s in _context.db_songs
select s.Song_Category ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "[LINQ Farm: Using Distinct and Avoiding Lambdas](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx)". I don't fully understand what you really want, but maybe this large explanation of distinct in LINQ can help you.