# Distinct in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I have a problem to translate this query in LINQ format:

```
select Version, count(distinct(idUser)) from HistoUsers
group by Version
```

What i have so far is this:

```
public static List<VersionsUsed> GetNumberOfCompaniesUsingEachVersions2()
{
    var foundUsers = (from hu in sdt.DataContext.HistoUsers

                      group hu by new { hu.Version, hu.IdUser } into g
                      select new VersionsUsed { nameVersion = g.Key.Version, NumberOfCompaniesUsingThisVersion = g.Count((g.Key.IdUser).distinct()) });

    return foundUsers.ToList();
}
```

Seems i have a syntax problem on distinct() 
Can anyone help me on this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx

Comment: and this is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786750/how-to-get-particular-column-distinct-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: If you're talking about the SQL version, it works perfectly with SQL server, no problem on this one for me

Answer (score 0):

```
from hu in sdt.DataContext.HistoUsers
group hu by new { hu.Version, hu.IdUser } into g
select new VersionsUsed 
 {  
   nameVersion = g.Key.Version, 
   NumberOfCompaniesUsingThisVersion = g.Select(c=>c.IdUser).Distinct().Count() 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It looks correct but i have way too much results. like if the distinct() was not used... i don't get why ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQER for this: it generates LINQ statements from equivalent SQL statements. You can download a 10-day trial version from http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select new VersionsUsed 
        { 
            nameVersion = g.Key.Version, 
            NumberOfCompaniesUsingThisVersion = g.Select(a=>a.IdUser).Distinct().Count()) 
        };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It looks correct but i have way too much results. like if the distinct() was not used... i don't get why ...

Answer (score 0):

Your distinct statement need to be like this:
`Distinct(...)`

1st letter in upper

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `distinct` use the keyword `first`. It will work:

```
var foundUsers = (from hu in sdt.DataContext.HistoUsers
   group hu by new { hu.Version, hu.IdUser } into g
   select new VersionsUsed { nameVersion = g.Key.Version, NumberOfCompaniesUsingThisVersion = g.Count((g.Key.IdUser).First()) });
return foundUsers.ToList();
```